How to line up a point to two views?
I managed somehow to use Blender's built-in photogrammetry to get the camera on two frames to be aligned to two "different" (actually, the same image but mirrored) reference images.
I am, of course, trying to recreate a 3D object from 2D images. With the view set to the camera and the reference image as background, I can easily trace over one of the reference images, but the points are only correct in that their 2D projections in that view are correct; when I switch to the other view, they are of course nowhere near where they should be.
By switching to the other view, moving the point to the correct location, switching back, and repeating many times, I can eventually get the 3D position of the point to be approximately correct. However, this is incredibly tedious.
Is there a faster way to go about this?
Ideally I would like to be able to do two things:

Be able to position a point in one view, then in the other view move it along the camera ray associated with the point's projected position in the first view.
Draw something (an annotation would be most convenient) in both views which represents the surface of a 2D curve projected in the respective views and obtain the intersection thereof.


Step 1:
Draw a "mesh" on top of one of the images (do all of these in ortographic views)

Step 2:
"Duplicate" that mesh in "object mode" and place over the second image.
As you know, the mesh will not match the image.

Step 3
"Move" the vertices of the new mesh to their right positions.
Important:

You shall NOT delete or add any vertice! (there must be a correlation between the two meshes and that correlation will be the index of each vertice)
Try to move vertices only horizontally or in the direction of the camera displacement (we want the points on each mesh to be stereoscopic pairs)


Step 4
LETS HAVE FUN!!!
Get these geometry nodes ready.
(PS: they work when you draw on the XY plane, while the camera displacement is on X)
Main setup:

This setup:

Centralizes the two meshes based on their bounding box
For each point, gets an intersection between lines coming from two virtual camera positions
Sets the position of each point at that intersection

Center images group

This just superposes both meshes at their centers, where "Vector mean" is a group making (Vector1 + Vector2) /  2
Intersect lines 2d
This is pure math intersecting two 2d lines

Result
A beautiful 3d mesh arising from the geonodes!
(You need to adjust the "camera distance" and the "camera offset" input values to get a sensible result)

File:

